# Crystal Report: skip page if detail section is null

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport, suppress, subreports

I have a subreport to filter the processing of specific products within a selected week set by the user. The subreport has 5 groups section and a detail section.
Specifically, the groups filter the data like this:

- Group1: filters the starting date of the process
- Group2: filters the products' group
- Group3: filters the products' code
- Group4: filters the products' number
- Group5: filters the products' sub-number

I use group1 section for writing some simple text. In the detail section, I put some fields. Now when I have no record in the detail section, the sub-report prints the text of group1. For example, because in the day of the print there isn't any processing work.

How can I skip the page if the detail section has no records? (Or perhaps it is necessary to suppress the group1?)

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click on the section, go to section expert, and check suppress blank section. This should hide the section if there are no values for that particular day

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had already tried this solution but as the Group1 formed by text, this is always printed even in the Details Section there are no records. In the Group1 Suppression Formulas, can I write somehow that Group1 is not printed if the Details Section is blank?

Answer (score 0):

You should try supressing the group 1 if the details section is null. I'm not sure that you can actually skip a page.

If you are wondering how to know if the details section is null, maybe using a shared variable inside that section, which will count how many records will be inside the details section, to be used in the supression formula for the group 1.